# With cucumber-jvm, how to get full gherkin description for a specific scenario during run time?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a set of tests with cucumber-jvm running concurrently by sending and receiving messages between Akka Actors. I was able to publish the test results including a scenario name and the pass/fail status to my dashboard website via RESTful APIs, which is achieved by using the @After hook that provides a injected scenario instance. Now I want to publish the detailed gherkin for the current scenario to the dashboard page also. However, the Scenario class in Cucumber-jvm doesn't provide any method to get the string of the story in Gherkin. I cannot just read the physical feature files, as they are all over the place and it's async, I don't know if there is a way to tie a feature file to a running scenario. Is there a way, to programmatically get the scenario description from (or bind with) a scenario instance from Cucumber?

Update: I am using the getName() and getId() and getStatus() methods in Scenario interface. What I need is something like a getScenarioDescription() which will return a String of a full Gherkin story for that scenario instance.

Comment: If not sure I understand your question correctly, but here goes. If you are looking for scenario description then you can use the getName() method of the scenario object.

Comment: Thanks @Grasshopper. I am using getName() to get the name of the scenario. However, I need more. I need the full story description for that scenario. Sorry, my question can be confusing. I updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Does gherkin full story mean all the steps for a scenario? You should look at creating a custom formatter - http://automationrhapsody.com/create-cucumber-jvm-custom-formatter/. Find many examples at - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/formatter